# Floating IP Address

Tags: networking, ip

What does 29 means in this floating ip range 192.168.1.0/29? I know it will give 6 usable floating ip but how can i know the what number other than 29 can I use to give me more range for my floating ip?

Answer (score 6):

The `/number` is a bit-mask where 0 means every single IP and /32 means just one (I don't think it's ever described with a /32, that's just implicit).

Of course this scales out for IPv6 but let's leave this at IPv4 for the moment ;)

```
/32 = 1 IP address. Outright.
/31 = NaN
/30 = 4 addresses, 2 usable
/29 = 8 addresses, 6 usable
/28 = 16 addresses, 14 usable
/27 = 32 addresses, 30 usable
/26 = 64 addresses, 62 usable
/25 = 128 addresses, 126 usable
/24 = 256 addresses, 254 usable (as we all know)
```

This carries on for larger and larger subnets.

Comment: FYI. the use of /31 subnets have been laid out in an [RFC](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3021.html) ages ago and [are used on point to point networks](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/jun/18/using-31-bit-subnets-on-point-point-links/). Their use is somewhat rare, but does happen.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 address is 32-bits in length. The dotted-decimal notation is the most common representation, as it makes connection between host address and subnet address more apparent, at least when using 8, 16 or 32 bit masks. The machine sees the address (as with all other data) as a string of bits. The dotted-decimal notation divides the 32-bit string into 4 parts, each being 8 bit long - in binary 8 bits may represent decimal numbers ranging from 0 to 255 so 255 is the maximum number for each field in the IP address.

Anyways, each address comprises of network part and host part (i.e. the network address is first N bits of the full address). The network part is often calculated from the full address by applying a **netmask** - you may just cut N first bits from the full address and you will get the network address. **This is the number you asked about.**

32 - N bits calculation yields the host space (you have to subtract 2 from that number - the network address and broadcast address). So 32 - 29 is 3, 3 ones in binary makes 8 in decimal. By subtracting 2 you get 6, which is the number of usable IP addresses.

It's good to know the algorithm, but making those calculations 'manually' is not practical - there are many subnet calculators available in the 'net, e.g. http://www.subnet-calculator.com/ Much data on the topic is available at [various](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) [pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4).